# i want the logged in user associated with account to see their attachments only when they click on attachment

Tags: visualforce, account, attachment, customer-portal

**My VF :**

```
<apex:page controller="AttachmentUploadController" sidebar="false" >  
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Program Documents " subtitle="Attach a File"/>

  <apex:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlock title="Upload a Attachment">

      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Save"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>

      <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2" id="block1">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="File Name" for="fileName"/>
          <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}" id="fileName"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file"/>
          <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Description" for="description"/>
          <apex:inputTextarea value="{!attachment.description}" id="description"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!flag}" >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstAttach}" var="att" >

       <apex:column HeaderValue="Name" >
                <apex:outputField value="{!att.name}" /> 
       </apex:column>
        <apex:column HeaderValue="Description" >
                 <apex:outputField value="{!att.Description}" /> 
        </apex:column>
                <apex:column HeaderValue="Last Modified Date" >
                <apex:outputField value="{!att.LastModifiedDate }" /> 
       </apex:column>



    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**MY Controller**

```
public class AttachmentUploadController {

    public String listatt { get; set; }

    public String item { get; set; }
    public String AccountTable { get; set; }
    Public boolean flag{ get; set; }
    public list<Attachment> lstAttach{
    get{
    return [Select name,description,LastModifiedDate from attachment where OwnerId =: UserInfo.getUserId()];

    }set;
    }


    public String getAttachmentUploadController() {
        return null;
    }


   public String getAccount() {
       return null;
    }

    public AttachmentUploadController() {
    flag=False;
    }



  public Attachment attachment {
  get {
      if (attachment == null)
        attachment = new Attachment();
      return attachment;
    }
  set;
  }

  public PageReference upload() {


   attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
   attachment.ParentId = '00163000005PcvVAAS'; // Account- FConnect Amend record id
   attachment.IsPrivate = true;
   flag=true;  
    try {
      insert attachment;

    } catch (DMLException e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
      return null;
    } finally {
      attachment = new Attachment(); 
    }

    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Attachment uploaded successfully'));
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem in more detail - I don't follow.

Comment: i want to make this page dynamic so which account is assciated with that user they should see the attachments they did..
For now as u see attachment.ParentId = '00163000005PcvVAAS'; is for one account. i want it for my all account

Comment: How is a User associated with an Account? Is it by Account ownership?